# Horizontal linear gradient from center ( non-radial )

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Is there a CSS linear gradient that originates from the center, but is not of the radial form?

---

**I have looked for documentation of this**

I have found plenty of [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for linear gradients from left to right and also for radial gradients. But this is not the effect I wish to produce.

---

**If you are wondering why not just use radial gradient**

This is for a sidebar that spans the height of the web page. I want it to look much like a **cylinder**. This is the reason for my not wanting to use a radial effect, as this would treat the sidebar as a sphere.

---

**Other options**

I understand that I could mirror two separate linear gradients and place them next to each other to pseudo achieve the desired effect.

---

**Final Question**

However, I am wondering if there is a prebuilt option for the actual desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but a single linear gradient should do the trick:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

This starts at black, goes to white in the center, and then back to black.